# how to import ROS .msg files in python which are not part of the usual .msg path?

Tags: python-3.x, import, ros, catkin, rospy

I am using [this](https://github.com/appie-17/tello_driver) driver here for ROS. The driver is inside my ROS catkin workspace (catkin_ws).
Inside this workspace I have another package from where I want to `import TelloStatus` which is located in `tello_driver/msg/TelloStatus.msg`

Usually messages (msg) in ROS are imported this way:

Examples:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
```

I think that these files are located at the following path on the system:

```
opt/ros/noetic/share
```

So my question is how can I import `TelloStatus` which is not part of this path but part of the `tello_driver` package?

I tried to import it the following way:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/usr/catkin_ws/src/tello_driver/msg/TelloStatus.msg')
import TelloStatus
```

but then I get this error message:

```
import TelloStatus
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TelloStatus'
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still import it the same way as any other message: `from tello_driver.msg import TelloStatus.msg`. The important part is you must have the correct environment sourced; this is the purpose of `source <install_dir/setup.bash>`. Make sure you source whatever *install* directory the build files are in. As a note, you should never try to add files in `src/` to be used at runtime this is what `install` or `devel` is for.

Editing based on your comment:

There's a few things to make sure happen here. First in the package `tello_driver` make sure the message files are actually set to build in `CMakeLists.txt`. Make sure it includes lines to add message files

```
add_message_files(
  FILES
  TelloStatus.msg
)
```

then make sure messages are being built

```
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)
```

Also make sure the `package.xml` has the dependencies to build messages by adding(if it's not already there)

```
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
<exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
```

Finally before building again make sure to clean your workspace with `catkin_make clean` then rebuild with `catkin_make`. After doing that and sourcing `devel/setup.bash` you can verify the message exists via `rosmsg show TelloStatus`

Comment: Hi first of all: thanks for your help! What I tried in an earlier stage was to import like you said with `from tello_driver.msg import TelloStatus` I am also aware of sourcing the environment. I did `source /home/usr/catkin_ws/devel/setup.sh ` and run the ros node which contains the aforementioned import with `rosrun package_name node_name.py` but then when I run `rostopic echo /tello/status` I got this error message: `ERROR: Cannot load message class for [tello_driver/TelloStatus]. Are your messages built?` I am sorry when the problem seems obvious to you but I am totally new to ROS.

Comment: @HughRivers no need to apologize. The whole ROS ecosystem can be a lot if you're new. I've edited my answer with some more info that should help.